# azure devops | keep history releases from specific branch

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to keep all the history from our master branch, 1 year

the history deleted after 2 or 3 months and is bad we want to keep our production history....

Answer (score 0):

To keep all the history from the master branch for a year, you can set up branch policies in Azure Devops.

Go to the Branches page in the Repos section of your project.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

Comment: I don't see in this documentation how to save releases from a certain branch (I already have a branch policy).

Answer (score 0):

You could see the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#set-release-retention-policies) for details.

If you are using an on-premises Team Foundation Server or Azure DevOps Server, you can specify release retention policy defaults and maximums for a project. If you are using Azure DevOps Services, you can view but not change these settings for your project.

And for every release pipelines, you could see retention policy for each stage but not specific branch. You could go to release pipelines and edit release then you could see 'retention' for the release.

[image]

For individual key releases, you can click on (…) of one release pipeline and choose “retain indenfinitely”.
[image]

BTW, neither the pipeline's retention policy nor the maximum limits set by the administrator are applied when you mark an individual run or release to be 'retained indefinitely'. It will remain until you stop retaining it indefinitely.